# Why does unescape work but decodeURI doesn't?

Tags: javascript

I have the following variable:

```
var string="Mazatl%E1n";
```

The string is returned like that by the server. All I want to do is decode that into: `Mazatlán`. I've tried the following:

```
var string="Mazatl%E1n";

alert(unescape(string));
alert(decodeURI(string));
```

*unescape* works fine but I don't want to use it because I understand it is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape), instead I tried *decodeURI* which fails with the following error:

> Uncaught URIError: URI malformed

Why ? Any help is appreciated.

```js
var string="Mazatl%E1n";

alert(unescape(string));
alert(decodeURI(string));
```

Comment: Look into [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)...

Comment: `escape()` and `unescape()`  are defined for ISO strings. `decodeURI()` and`encodeURI()` are defined for UTF-8 strings.

Comment: @JohanKarlsson is heading in the right direction. %E1 is the Unicode encoding, but URIs use UTF-8, so the correct encoding is %C3%A1. You can see this by running `encodeURIComponent("Mazatlán")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get the error because `%E1` is the Unicode encoding, but `decodeURI()` expects UTF-8.

You'll either have to create your own unescape function, for example:

```js
function unicodeUnEscape(string) {
  return string.replace(/%u([\dA-Z]{4})|%([\dA-Z]{2})/g, function(_, m1, m2) {
    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt("0x" + (m1 || m2)));
  })
}

var string = "Mazatl%E1n";
document.body.innerHTML = unicodeUnEscape(string);
```

or you could change the server to send the string encoded in UTF-8 instead, in which case you can use `decodeURI()`

```js
var string = "Mazatl%C3%A1n"
document.body.innerHTML = decodeURI(string);
```

Comment: Could it be possible you document the regex ?

Comment: It matches a `%` followed by either `u` and 4 hexadecimal digits, or `%` followed by 2 hexadecimal digits: https://regex101.com/r/cC4tN4/1

Comment: I would recommend @JohanKarlsson that you add an i (insensitive) after the g of the regex, as %2f and %2F are both valid encoding

Answer (score 2):

URI supports the ASCII character-set , and the correct  format encoding for `á` is `%C3%A1` (in UTF-8 encoding)

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hsuba42y/1/)

---

[escape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape) and unescape use an hexadecimal escape sequences
(which is different ..);
so the value you're getting form the server has been encoded using `escape(string)`.

Answer (score 1):

The [decodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI) function expects a valid URI as its parameter. If you are only trying to decode a string instead of a full URI, use [decodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)